# How to change only the one value of a object in a state

Tags: reactjs

My state looks like :

```
this.state = {
  sundayTime:{
    start:"",
    end:""
  },
  mondayTime:{
    start:"",
    end:""
  }
};

  handleSundayClick = (time) => {
    const sundayTimeStart = time.format(format).split(":").join("");
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
      sundayTime: { start: sundayTimeStart, ...prevState.sundayTime }
    }
  });
  };
  handleMondayClick = (time) => {
    const mondayTimeStart = time.format(format).split(":").join("");
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
      sundayTime: { start: mondayTimeStart, ...prevState.mondayTime }
    }
    });
  };
  //End Time
  handleSundayClickEnd = (time) => {
    const sundayTimeEnd = time.format(format).split(":").join("");
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
      sundayTime: { ...prevState.sundayTime ,end: sundayTimeEnd}
    }
    });
  };
  handleMondayClickEnd = (time) => {
    const mondayTimeEnd = time.format(format).split(":").join("");
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
      sundayTime: { ...prevState.mondayTime ,end: mondayTimeEnd}
    }
    });
  };
  
  handleClick = () => {
    console.log("State:", this.state);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <TimePicker
          placeholder="Sunday"
          format={format}
          onOk={this.handleSundayClick}
        />
        <TimePicker
          placeholder="Monday"
          format={format}
          onOk={this.handleMondayClick}
        />

        {/* End Time */}
        <TimePicker
          placeholder="Sunday"
          format={format}
          onOk={this.handleSundayClickEnd}
        />
        <TimePicker
          placeholder="Monday"
          format={format}
          onOk={this.handleMondayClickEnd}
        />

        <Button onClick={this.handleClick}> Click to Print </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I just need to change the value of key `end` in the sundayTime state.

the above code doesn't give the desired output.

The console.log looks exactly like the state with empty objects.

NOTE: It uses TimePicker from antd, to reproduce it you must import antd or code sandbox link : [CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-smoke-vzkt9?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Try like this: `this.setState({sundayTime: { ...this.state.sundayTime, end: time }})`

Comment: `this.setState(prevState => { return { ...prevState, sundayTime: { ...prevState.sundayTime, end: time }}; });`

Comment: @PriyankKachhela That dint work. It actually only changed the end time when I console logged it at the end

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković I have edited the code and for more insights check the codesandbox link at the end of the question

Comment: @SaiKrishnadas You didn't use previous state, read my comment again.

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković I did, Please check the edited code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always copy the current state in local var, change value and set state with new value. Something like:

```
this.state = {...};

let result = Object.assign({}, this.state); //<--copy this.state into result
result.sundayTime.end = "newValue"; //<-- set sundayTime.end
this.setState({ state: result });  //<-- set state with new value
```

**EDIT**

The codesandbox you provides has an error on every `this.setState`. Infact you wrote:

```
const sundayTime = time.format(format).split(":").join("");
this.setState({
  sundayTime : { start: sundayTime , ...time.state.sundayTime }
});
```

But should be (in case you want to adopt @hendra solution):

```
const sundayTime = time.format(format).split(":").join("");
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        sundayTime: {...prevState.sundayTime, start: sundayTime},
      };
    }, () => {
      console.log(this.state) //<-- setState has a callback!
    });
```

As you can see, I used `this.setState`'s callback to verify if state is correctly set. And the result is:

[image]

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-architecture-cdxxe) your codesandbox modified.

Comment: I have edited the code and for more insights check the codesandbox link at the end of the question

Comment: WORKS PREFECT :)  Thanks

Comment: @SaiKrishnadas happy to ear that. Have a nice coding =)

Comment: Why would you accept this answer instead of the one @hendra wrote way before?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for object literals.

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  return {
    ...prevState,
    sundayTime: {...prevState.sundayTime, end: time},
  };
});
```

Comment: This dint work, as at the end of console logging the state , gave me mostly empty object

Comment: I have edited the code and for more insights check the codesandbox link at the end of the question

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `Spread Operator`

React state should be treated as immutable so you should first copy the state then change the copy and finally setState the copy

```
 handleSundayClick = (time) => {
    const copy = { ...this.state };
    const sundayTime= {
      ...copy.sundayTime,
      start: time.format(format).split(":").join("")
    };
    this.setState({ ...copy, sundayTime});
    //if you set a different name than sundayTime then the line above
    //should be like this
    //`this.setState({ ...copy, sundayTime: "name that you set"});`
  };
```

Comment: I doesn't work, check out the codesandbox in the bottom of the question. I have tried your solution.

Comment: I Saw codesandbox, you changed sundayTime  to sundayTimeStart, so it didn't work. If you want change the name you should change the code that I sent : "this.setState({ ...this.state,sundayTime:sundayTimeStart });"